# How to pass data from checkbox to DOMPDF?

Tags: laravel, backend, dompdf

I want to create a system that makes dynamic to-do lists. Every user has a checkbox, if checked I want them to be included in the pdf, if unchecked I don't want to include them. This is for creating a list on the day itself, just for the people that are in the office.

I tried making it work with a post request, but then there is no way to download the pdf.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.